# Pattern matching in purescript

Tags: purescript

How can I implement `head` or `singleton` function in purescript by pattern matching? The problem is that the compiler requires the explicit definition of the broadest pattern, but I can't generate a default value for a type that I don't know.

```
fromSingleton :: forall a. a -> Array a -> a 
fromSingleton _   [x] = x
fromSingleton def []    = def
```

returns:

```
A case expression could not be determined to cover all inputs.
  The following additional cases are required to cover all inputs:

    _ _

  Alternatively, add a Partial constraint to the type of the enclosing value.
```

But this proposal looks dummy, I can't  add:

```
fromSingleton _ _     = ??? (a -- is any type, how can I implement default for it?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fromSingleton :: forall a. a -> Array a -> a
fromSingleton def x = case Array.uncons x of
  Nothing -> def
  Just { head } -> head
```

This should work. Your original version covered all cases for the first argument, but for the second argument, you only covered the case of empty array and singleton array.